# How can i get server time from firebase using angular?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am working with firebase and angular application. I was working with `new Date()`, but now our requirement is to change this function to server time. But I have no idea how can i get server time from firebase.

[image]

**Code**

I save time in firebase like this.

```
 this.projectForm.value.createdAt = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
 this.firestore.collection('projects').add(this.projectForm.value);
```

But no idea how can I get the value

```
this.firestore.collection('projects').doc(this.projectId).get().subscribe(snapshot => {
    const project: any = snapshot.data();
});
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not missing out on something here, I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. What exactly are you trying to do with the project?

You are declaring a local variable in the

```
this.firestore.collection('projects').doc(this.projectId).get().subscribe(snapshot => {
    const project: any = snapshot.data();
});
```

snippet.

Therefore you can only access the project in this codeblock.

Try

```
this.firestore.collection('projects').doc(this.projectId).get().subscribe(snapshot => {
    const project: any = snapshot.data();
    console.log('CreatedAt', project.createdAt);
});
```

And check the console for output.

PS:
You are using TypeScript you should define a type for `Project`. Using `any` type is very bad practice.